# cannot convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date with JXDatePicker

Tags: java, sql

i am using a JXDatepicker here. i dont know what to do with the error please help me. i tried a lot but failed. [image]

i tried to print what cause this error and it prints this message. i want the format to be yyyy/MM/dd cause i want it to insert into the database.

**AddProductGUI.java**

```
txtExpiration = new JXDatePicker();                     txtExpiration.setName("Expiration");
txtExpiration.setBorder(null);
txtExpiration.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"));
```

**AddProduct.java**

```
public java.util.Date returnDate(JXDatePicker txtExpiration, Boolean isExpiring) {
        if (isExpiring) {
            return txtExpiration.getDate();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**ActionToDatabase.java**

```
if (!DatabaseValidator
                            .isExistingData(
                                    "select ProductID from tblIndividualProduct where ProductID =?",
                                    product.getProductID())) {

                        sql = "insert into tblIndividualProduct (ProductId,Code,Expiration,Note,UpdatedPrice,PriceChanged) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                        connection
                                .setPreparedStatement((PreparedStatement) connection
                                        .getConnection().prepareStatement(sql));
                        connection.getPreparedStatement().setString(1,
                                product.getProductID());
                        connection.getPreparedStatement().setString(2,
                                product.getCode());

                        //connection.getPreparedStatement().setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(product.getExpiration().getTime()));
                        **connection.getPreparedStatement().setDate(3, (java.sql.Date)product.getExpiration());**

                        connection.getPreparedStatement().setString(4,
                                product.getNote());
                        connection.getPreparedStatement().setDouble(5,
                                product.getPrice());
                        connection.getPreparedStatement().setBoolean(6,
                                product.getPriceChanged());
                        connection.getPreparedStatement().executeUpdate();
                        System.out
                                .println("Successfully added individual product ("
                                        + product.getProductID()
                                        + ") to the database");
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new instance of a `java.sql.Date` using the `java.util.Date` as the base value, for example

```
connection.getPreparedStatement().setDate(3, 
    (product.getExpiration() == null ? 
        null : 
        new java.sql.Date(product.getExpiration().getTime())));
```

It would be possible to pass a `java.sql.Date` to `JXDatePicker` as `java.sql.Date` extends from `java.util.Date`, but it won't work the other way around (you can't cast a `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date` without first knowing that the object is acutally a `java.sql.Date` masquerading as a `java.util.Date`

Comment: i already tried that new jaba.sql.Date(product.getExpiration().getTime()) but i get a nullpointer because i also want to return null when its the product is not expiring.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you could use a tri operator to detect the `null` from the `produce` and set the column value accordingly - see update...

Comment: thanks sir you save me everytime. i owe you a lot. :D